# Upload file over 512Ko doesn't work with laravel +Wamp

Tags: php, laravel-5, wampserver

When i try to upload a file over **512kb** on my application, after submit my page charging indefinitely.

PHP info :

```
max_file_uploads    20  20
upload_max_filesize 2M  2M
post_max_size   8M  8M
```

I really not understand what i do bad.

```
Wamp 3.0.6 Laravel 5.4
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Do you restart your server after doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but finally my error came from the cache of my browser. after emptying it worked. Thank you !